# Edit bounty duration?

Tags: support, bounties

I added a bounty to a (IMO) well phrased [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012797/autorotation-on-a-gallery-willanimaterotation-isnt-invoked) and okayed it a bit too quickly. Can I shorten the duration of it to "today"? Since if there's no answer real soon now (tm) I'll code my own viewcontroller from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A bounty will always last for seven days.

And be aware that even if this were possible, you still would not regain the amount of reputation you invested in the bounty anyway.